# Failed assertion : 'email != null'?

Tags: database, flutter, null

does anyone know why my result is null? When I want to SignUp the debug console display : Failed assertion: line 183 pos 12: 'email != null': is not true. And it displays null. This is my SignUp code when I press SignUp Button and the other code ist my auth  class. If anyone knows please comment.

```
 Future <void> signUp() async {

     if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
       setState(() {

         isLoading = true;
       });

       await authService.signUpWithEmailAndPassword(_email,
           _password).then((result)  {
         if(result != null){

           Map<String,String> userDataMap = {
             "Username" : _Username,
             "Email" : _email,
             "Nation" : _Nation,
           };

           databaseService.addUserInfo(userDataMap);

           HelperFunction.saveUserLoggedInSharedPreference(true);
           HelperFunction.saveUserNameSharedPreference(_Username);
           HelperFunction.saveUserEmailSharedPreference(_email);
           HelperFunction.saveUserNationSharedPreference(_Nation);

           Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
               builder: (context) => LoadingBarForUserCreation()
           ));
         }else{
           print(result);
         }
       }).catchError((e){
         _showSettingPanelForEmail();
       });
     }
```

AuthService

```
class AuthService{

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Userf _userFromFirebaseUser(User user){

    return user != null ? Userf(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  Stream<Userf> get user {
    return _auth.onAuthStateChanged
        .map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }


  Future signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      User user = (await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password)).user;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future signUpWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      User user = (await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password)).user;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }





  Future signOut() async {
    try {
      return await _auth.signOut();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }



}
```

Comment: The validator is usually defined on the TextFormField, which isn't present in what you posted in this revision.

Comment: Ok but what is the solution? :)